# List - restrict rows based on values and who logged in

Tags: list

Suppose a SP list like below:

### prj#      project       PM             Director          VP

1             prj1           John           Smith              Joel

2              prj2           John           Nina               Susan

3              prj3           Ahmed          Nina               Joel

4              prj4           Steve          Nina               Susan

5              prj5           Steve          Hagen              Allan

What I want to do is, when John who is PM logs in he could only view first 2 records, or when Nina logs in she gets record 2,3 and 4, etc.

Few users will see everything, no restrictions. say CEO or SVPs

Is this possible?

And can this be done in a better way than this type of list.

Comment: have look this example:http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/03/21/sharepoint-easy-row-level-security-aspx/

Answer (score 1):

Expecting the PM field to be user field, you can create a view which filters by PM. Simply set PM to [Me] and this will result in showing all those rows where current user is PM.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict with item level permission by workflow on item created.
Use "Replace List Item Permissions" action.

Or by browser to click item and click "Item Permissions" and set individual permission for group or single user.

[image: Item Level Permissions]

Be aware, this method should use with small amount of data